# Highcharts dynamically change bar color based on value

Tags: json, highcharts

I am creating a column type graph using json data. Here is the JS function i call to get the data using ajax call and plot the chart.

```
function getChart(){
    var categorySeries = [];
    var dataSeries = [];            
    var url = "CallToControllerURL";

    $.getJSON(url, function(response) {             
        $.each(response, function(i, item) {
            categorySeries .push(response[i].dateVal);                  
            dataSeries.push(response[i].count);             
        });

        $('#chartDiv').highcharts({
            chart : {type : 'column'},
            title : {text : 'Date vs Count'},
            xAxis : {categories : categorySeries, crosshair : true},
            yAxis : {allowDecimals: false, min : 0, title : { text : 'Count'}},
            plotOptions : { column : {  pointPadding : 0.2, borderWidth : 0,    allowPointSelect: true  } },
            series : [ {name : 'Nbr of Records',data : dataSeries } ]
        });             
    });
}
```

I want to be able to modify the color of bar for any day if the count is greater than a particular value, say 10.

This is how the json input to the function.

```
[{"id":3,"dateVal":"2015-11-12","count":6},{"id":2,"dateVal":"2015-11-11","count":8},{"id":1,"dateVal":"2015-11-10","count":5}]
```

Any suggestions how i can do this?

Comment: Change color specifically, or in general? If two bars are over 10, can they both be the same color?

Comment: Yes, So lets say i have 7 bars in the graph for a week's data. Any day when the count is greater than 10, i want the color of bar to be red. For all values less than 10 a diff color or default one it ok.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use color zones ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.zones)) to have different colors based on the value of a column.

An example with values below/above the value 10 having different colors ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmvzrLdf/)):

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        zones: [{
            value: 10, // Values up to 10 (not including) ...
            color: 'blue' // ... have the color blue.
        },{
            color: 'red' // Values from 10 (including) and up have the color red
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: How to update few columns (particular value) out of many columns?

Answer (score 2):

In the parser you can replace that:

```
$.each(response, function(i, item) {
        categorySeries .push(response[i].dateVal);                  
        dataSeries.push(response[i].count);             
    });
```

with

```
$.each(response, function(i, item) {
    categorySeries.push(response[i].dateVal);
    if(response[i].count >= 10) {
        dataSeries.push({
        y: response[i].count,
        color: 'red'
      });
    }
    else {
        dataSeries.push(response[i].count);
    }
});
```

or use [zones](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.zones).

Comment: I had been trying something similar but was not using the Y axis option. Now i know what was missing. This works and so does the zones feature from the API.

Answer (score 1):

```
plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    zones: [
                        {
                            value: -1, 
                            color: 'red', 
                        },
                        {
                            color: 'green'//default color
                        },
                    ],
                },
            }
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.