# Change color code on colum, depending on data value (highchartJS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I have some problem on iterating the data for this chart. It is using HighchartJS, very simple, but I need to color the step's column if the value is less than 1000, and does not works.

This is my EEFE function for the color property. Where this.data trows undefined. Any idea how to print the correct color?

```
series: [{
  data: [1600, 3000, 400, 700, 1234, 765, 76],
  color: (function() {
      for (var i in this.data) {
        var value = this.data[i];
        if (value > 1000)
        {
          this.value = '#75ad74';
          return this.value;
        } 
        else if (value < 1000)
        {
          this.value = '#FF0000';
          return this.value;
        }
      }
    })()
}]
```

Link to my example

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/fkytsubb/)
**UPDATE**

Thanks all!, @HalvorStrand I have used zones property, now works like a charm.

```
 zones: [{
      value: 1000, 
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      color: 'red'
    }],
```

Comment: Because in the IIFE `this` refers to the window object.

Comment: So you want to color columns >1000 in one color and <1000 in another color? No IIFE, just use `zones`.

Comment: As @HalvorStrand noted, zones will work. See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800720/highcharts-dynamically-change-bar-color-based-on-value

Answer (score 0):

As i say in the comment the `this` in the IIFE is the window object. If you would like to create a self structuring object out of thin air and pass it as an argument you can do like these. I am not very familiar with HighCharts but i guess the second snippet is the correct data structure in which individual points have their own color definition.

```js
var myObj = {
          xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                allowPointSelect: true
            }
        },
  
        series: [{
                  data: [1600, 3000, 400, 700, 1234, 765, 76],
                 color: []
                 }],
          init: function() {
                  this.series[0].color = this.series[0].data.map(e => e >= 1000 ? '#75ad74' : '#FF0000');
                  delete this.init;
                  return this;
                }
}.init();

console.log(myObj);
```

I guess this is the correct `series[0].data` structure for HighCharts.

```js
var myObj = {
          xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                allowPointSelect: true
            }
        },
  
        series: [{
                  data: [1600, 3000, 400, 700, 1234, 765, 76],
                 }],
          init: function() {
                  this.series[0].data = this.series[0].data.map(e => e >= 1000 ? {y: e, color: '#75ad74'}
                                                                               : {y: e, color: '#FF0000'});
                  delete this.init;
                  return this;
                }
}.init();

console.log(myObj);
```

In real application you will provide this object definition as a parameter to the `highcharts` function.