# Highchart - colors depending on values

Tags: highcharts

I want to give a color for bars depending on their values.

1. For example if you a bar value 5000 then the color should be Dark RED similar for 3000 less darker than 5000 bar values so on...
2. I want to add total space like 100TB above all bars(some text on my bar value)

   `

   Availability Bar Chart

   ```
    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Disk Utility'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population">Application Name</a>'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Checkout', 'Hermes', 'Hybris', 'Marketplace', 'Mobile'],
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Used (TB)',
                    align: 'high'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' millions'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                                style: {
                                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                                }
                            }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -40,
                y: 80,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
                shadow: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                data: [107, 311, 635, 203, 244]
            }]
        });
    });
   ```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eooe2b8r/)

Comment: This point is not clear >> Also I want to add total space like 100TB above all bars

Comment: pls help me to sort issue 1 updated

Comment: you want to add space 100 TB, means you want to add extra space above column? OR you want to place some text with datalabel  to show how much used and how much space is remaining out of total ?

Comment: like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/eooe2b8r/2/

Comment: you are correct but i want to get value from array

Comment: instead of doing some static text

Comment: What's your array, could you put and example what exactly from array you want to show. put array here in comment or update question.

Comment: [100,200,300,400,500]

Comment: Adding two related posts for others with similar problems: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755236/highcharts-change-bar-color-based-on-value, 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800720/highcharts-dynamically-change-bar-color-based-on-value

Answer (score 4):

[Here is updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/eooe2b8r/1/)

You can use "Zones" in plotoptions to define a range and relevant color , as per code below :

```
zones: [{
        value: 200,  
        color: '#bdbdbd'  
    },{
        value:300,
        color: '#ff0000'  
    },
    {
        value:500,
        color: 'blue'  
    },{
        value:800,
        color: 'black'  
    }]
```