# Yii Highchart extension - Change color based on value

Tags: javascript, php, yii, highcharts, extension-methods

So, I use this [highcharts](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/highcharts/) extension on Yii.
And I fetch the data using database (from my controller). And the view looks like this:

```
<div class="hero-unit" id="content" style="position:relative;border: solid green">
<div style="max-width:100%;overflow:auto;">
    <div style="width:2200px;">
        <center> 
            <?php
            $label = array(); //inisiasi label axis
            $nilai = array(); //inisiasi nilai data
            foreach ($dataProvider3->getData() as $i => $ii) {
                $label[$i] = array($ii['no'] . '. ' . $ii['namapek']);//this is fetched from SQL syntax in controller
                $nilai[$i] = (float) $ii['pek']; //this is fetched from SQL syntax in controller
            }
            $this->widget('application.extensions.highcharts.HighchartsWidget', array(
                'scripts' => array(
                    'modules/exporting',
                    'themes/epcGray',
                    'highcharts-more',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                    'chart' => array('defaultSeriesType' => 'column', 'backgroundColor' => 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'),
                    'title' => FALSE,
                    'legend' => array(
                        'enabled' => false,
                    ),
                    'xAxis' => array(
                        'categories' => $label,
                    ), //nama axis
                    'yAxis' => array(
                        'min' => 0,
                        'title' => array(
                            'text' => 'Percentage'
                        ),
                    ),
                    'series' => array(
                        array('data' => $nilai)//data,
                    ),
                    'tooltip' => array(
                        'formatter' => 'js:function() {return "<b>Step "+ this.x +"</b><br/>" + "Finished: "+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) +"%"; }',
                    ),
                    'plotOptions' => array(
                        'column' => array(
                            'zones' =>
                            array('value' => 50, 'color' => '#EB4011'),
                            array('value' => 120, 'color' => '#aaff99'),
                        ),
                        'series' => array(
                            'point' => array(
                                'events' => array(
                                    'click' => 'js:function() {
                                var cat = this.category;
                                var res = parseInt(cat, 10);
                                window.open ("index.php?r=reports/rinci&id=" + res); }',
                                )
                            ),
                        )
                    ),
                    'credits' => array('enabled' => false),
                )
            ));
            ?>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699882/highchart-colors-depending-on-values?noredirect=1&lq=1) about changing the bar colors based on the value. But it's in json format, and I need to use it Yii widget format. I thought it's easy to do it but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

I tried to put this:

```
'colorByPoint' => true,
```

Above the `zones =>` thingy, the colors change by points but not by value as I want them to. I also put it under `series` array, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have tried a lot of things to make it work.
But it seems to be the flaws from the extension itself.

So I directly use the highchart js files on my view. That works fine. Anyone faces the same problem, I recommend leaving the extension if it lacks too many useful functions.

These are the required js files:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
```

Use the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699882/highchart-colors-depending-on-values?noredirect=1&lq=1).