# Highcharts column chart color by single color but with different brightness level as per respective column value

Tags: javascript, highcharts, colors

I have implemented `HighCharts Column Chart`, which is colored by single blue color. I want to color each column of a chart as per the value of column. For example, if 1st column having 10 value and 2nd column having 20 value then blue color's brightness should get change for both columns as per their values dynamically.

I found some solutions which are coloring by different colors to columns a by conditions. But I want to change brightness level of color. color value will be any single value.

Comment: Colours don't really have 'brightness', they are really just different colours. So use the same solution but set the colours that you want (light blue, medium blue, dark blue, etc.). Also, you should include your current code in the question

Comment: but values are dynamic, sometimes 10 sometimes 1000...how to apply conditions then?

Comment: based on percentage.

Comment: I tried by percentage...will add code for the same...it is resulting in opposite way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34801749/838807) for providing the suggestion of using 'zones' which provides the basis to my answer.

You can just specify the different colours as different 'shades' of whatever colour you want to use, in this case blue. There are 4 zones, each with a different type of blue.

In order to work with dynamic data (i.e. you don't know the value range) you can calculate the zone ranges based on a percentage of the maximum value in your input data array. In this case 4 zones are defined at 25%, 50%, 75% and 100%.

```
var d = [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 10.0, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6];
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, d);

$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        zones: [{
          value: max * 0.25,
          color: '#aaf'
        }, {
          value: max * 0.5,
          color: '#88f'
        }, {
          value: max * 0.75,
          color: '#66f'
        }, {
          color: '#44f'
        }]
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: d
    }]
  });
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zsj4fsLm/).

Comment: seems the answer what I want...Trying this